# Remove pixels from jquery height

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I minus 100px from the returned height?

```
function HomePageSize() {
    $('#home').css({
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height()
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are not kidding? Just add `-100`?

Comment: I'm sure I just answered this question ??

Comment: @3rror404 You're right i am also been though this one few minutes ago  :)

Comment: Seriously? Posting the same question twice within a few minutes? After the first one has already got some answers, moreover?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
height: $(window).height() - 100
```

Comment: I dont think this deserves an answer, this kind of behaviour should not be encouraged

Comment: @Dale it is better to learn by reading answers to existing questions, not by asking duplicate questions. Also, insulting people is never helpful.

Comment: No, I'm not arrogant. The question is basic BASIC programming. You clearly havent tried **anything**, your first try should've been the `-100`. Apart from that, I was refering to the rules, ie showing "What have you tried".